# Interesting output in a simple PHP webpage

Tags: php

Here is a very simple PHP page with one javascript function in it. I am seeing the output differently. I am not able to understand why is it behaving that way.

In the code below, x echoes as 012012, but when I pass it into a javascript function and display it in an innerHTML, it displays differently as 5130 ??!!

Can anyone help ?

```
<?php
    $x= date("mY");
    echo $x;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myfunc1(y)
            {
                div1 = document.getElementById("mydiv1")
                div1.innerHTML = y;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body <?php echo "onload='myfunc1(".$x.")'>";?>
    <div id="mydiv1" style="background:#efefef;border:1px solid green;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML output

```
012012<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myfunc1(y)
            {
                div1 = document.getElementById("mydiv1")
                div1.innerHTML = y;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='myfunc1(012012)'>    <div id="mydiv1" style="background:#efefef;border:1px solid green;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML output (screenshot)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the problems of not specifying your number type, and leaving JavaScript to parse it as octal. Also, you're echoing your `x` variable outside of your `html` document-root (which is invalid). Similarly you've posted your server-side script, but not your rendered html. Which makes it more difficult than necessary (not impossible, just more difficult) to understand what the JavaScript's working with.

Comment: Paste the HTML source to show us what your PHP ouputs.

Comment: Your `body` tag isn´t ended properly. Try `<body onload="myFunc1('<?php echo $x; ?>');">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `012012` is being treated as an int.  But, since it starts with `0`, JavaScript treats it as base 8 (octal), and therefore converts it to `5130`.

You need to wrap `012012` in quotes, so JavaScript treats it as a string.  Also, I suggest only using PHP to echo the value you need, not the entire function call. Makes it *slightly* easier to debug.

```
<body onload="myfunc1('<?php echo $x;?>')">
```

Comment: I replaced my body statement with the one provided in your comment and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Because a number prefixed with a 0 is treated as octal by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use Smarty, is a framework template PHP!

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $foo = date('Y');
?>
```

**Simple Print PHP Code**

```
<body onload="myFunctionJS('<?php echo $foo;?>')">
```

**Simple Tags PHP(It is not recommended)**

```
<body onload="myFunctionJS('<?=$foo;?>')">
```

> ***USE SMARTY TEMPLATE FRAMEWORK***
>
> **Smarty Template Framework(PHP Code):**
>
> ```
> <?php
>     $smarty = new Smarty;
>     $var = date('Y');
>     $smarty->assign( 'foo' , $var );
> ?>
> ```
>
> **Smarty Template Framework(Template Code):**
>
> ```
> <body onload="myFunctionJS('{$foo}')">
> ```

Comment: @Olaf Erlandsen Will definitely check that out...Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
<body <?php echo "onload='myfunc1(".$x.")'>";?>
```

should be

```
<body <?php echo "onload='myfunc1(".$x.")'>";?>>
```

The body tag is not closed

Comment: Personally I'd suggest it should be `<body onload="myfunc1(<?php echo "$x"; ?>)">`

Comment: To which I fullheartedly agree.

Comment: @DavidThomas: `<?php echo "$x"; ?>`.  The `"` around `$x` are useless.  Just do `echo $x`.

Comment: @Rocket, that occurred to me as I was writing that comment but, to my shame, I couldn't remember if leaving out the `"` would cause problems or not...sigh. Note to self: I should follow my instincts next time..! =D